# unable to open file in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to open these two files and read their contents into two different arrays, but whenever I try and open them I get the unable to open file dialog? I don't see anything incorrect but I am not a strong c++ user.

```
std::ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("fives.txt"); 
if (inFile.is_open()) 
{
    while (! inFile.eof() ) 
    {
        getline (inFile,line);
        fives[loop] = line;
        cout << fives[loop] << endl; 
        loop++;
    }
    inFile.close(); 
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";

inFile.open("search.txt");
loop=0;
if (inFile.is_open()) 
{
    while (! inFile.eof() ) 
    {
        getline (inFile,line);
        search[loop] = line;
        cout << search[loop] << endl; 
        loop++;
    }
    inFile.close(); 
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: Which of your two `if` clauses is triggering the message?

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? If so, do you have read permission?

Comment: What do you mean by "open file *dialog*"?

Comment: do they exist in the current directory? Note, the "current directory" is the directory the program is executed from, but doesn't have to be the one the program file is saved in.

Comment: both if statements are, and by dialog I meant the cout statements.

Comment: @littleadv I've added both files to the resources in visual studio

Comment: resources? What does it mean? `std::ifstream` is looking for files on the disk, not resources.

Comment: @Stratosja you just answered your own question. The files don't exist in the executable's working directory.

Comment: An aside, unrelated to your question: Please don't use `eof()` as a loop condition. It almost always produces a buggy program (as it does, in fact, in your program.) Use `while(getline(...))` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files must exist in the *current directory*, where the *current directory* is the directory from which the program was executed (not necessarily the one where the executable is saved at).

In your case, you saved the files with the resources, not with the resulting binary (I'm guessing you're running from within the VC++, by default it sets the current directory to where the binary is stored), so the program cannot find them. Use either relative path to where the resources are, or copy the files you're looking for into the directory you're running from.